# using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider and ReadAsMultipartAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How would i go about using `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` and `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync` in a `ApiController`?

I have googled a few tutorials but I can't get any of them to work, I'm using .net 4.5.

Code:

```cs
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    const string StoragePath = @"T:\WebApiTest";
    public async void Post()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(Path.Combine(StoragePath, "Upload"));
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
            foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
                    
                string fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                
                if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
                    fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
                    
                if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                    
                File.Copy(fileData.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(StoragePath, fileName));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
     }
}
```

I get the exception

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
> complete.

when the `await task;` runs.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or have a working example in asp.net?

Comment: If `t.IsFaulted` is true it means there was an exception, and it will be populated in the `Exception` property.  See what the exception was.  Alternatively just `await task;` to simplify the code and, among other things, it will re-throw any exceptions.

Comment: after replacing the ContinueWith and the if sentence after with "await task;" i get "Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete."

Comment: I think the following post may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177237/webapi-ajax-formdata-upload-with-extra-parameters

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I resolved the error, i don't understand what this has to do with end of multipart stream but here is the working code:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    const string StoragePath = @"T:\WebApiTest";
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(Path.Combine(StoragePath, "Upload"));
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
            foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
                }
                string fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
                {
                    fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
                }
                if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
                {
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                }
                File.Move(fileData.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(StoragePath, fileName));
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see an example of how this Post method is called by a client?

Comment: I get the following error at the line starts with `await`:
"Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream."

Do you have any suggestions about what might be the cause?

Comment: @ciuncan check the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602845/post-error-either-binaryread-form-files-or-inputstream-was-accessed-before-t it might help you!

Comment: @Peter thanks, I saw that post, and couldn't see any suggestions for solution but rather what could reasons be. They also mention something wrong with Web API implementation, but it is a one year old post. I upgraded Web API libraries to edge version (currently 5.2.0). Actually my code is exactly the same as yours, and I also checked the tutorial code in asp.net site as well: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2 .
I can't see what else is accessing the underlying `InputStream` etc. other than `ReadAsMultipartAsync` method.

Comment: @ciuncan im sorry i have no idea whats wrong, im not even using this code any more so i can't say if its in working condition or not..

Comment: @Peter thanks anyways, I appreciate your response. I don't use it anymore either, i replaced the action argument with `IEnumerable<byte[]>`, and I could get it work. :D

Comment: What is the different? What did you change? the path combine?

Comment: The problem with the original code was that the API didn't (and had no way to) know when the `async void` method finishes. That's why it managed to dispose of the stream on your way to read it. With `Task<>`-returning method, the calling code has a chance to know when you are ready with the request, and closes the streams when you really don't need them any more. Every time you see `async void` you should feel bad.

Comment: for users just arriving, code in this answer indeed works as-is.. copy/paste

Answer (score 7):

At first, you should define **enctype** to **multipart**/form-data in ajax request header.

```
[Route("{bulkRequestId:int:min(1)}/Permissions")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Pair>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutCertificatesAsync(int bulkRequestId)
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");

        var streamProvider = new MyStreamProvider(uploadPath);

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

        List<Pair> messages = new List<Pair>();
        
        foreach (var file in streamProvider.FileData)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
            messages.Add(new Pair(fi.FullName, Guid.NewGuid()));
        }

        //if (_biz.SetCertificates(bulkRequestId, fileNames))
        //{
            return Ok(messages);
        //}
        //return NotFound();
    }
    return BadRequest();
}

public class MyStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public MyStreamProvider(string uploadPath) : base(uploadPath)
    {
    }
    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty));
        return fileName;
    }
}
```