# Webapi ajax formdata upload with extra parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I'm using jQuery ajax to upload file but want to add some parameters on webapi method, here is:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", $("#file")[0].files[0]);
data.append("myParameter", "test"); // with this param i get 404

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/my/upload/',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The Webapi controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public string Upload(string myParameter)
    {
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count.ToString() + " / " + myParameter;
    }
}
```

Without myParameter everything work but when I include myParameter on formdata and api method I get 404, any chance to make it work?

Comment: mate can you post the complete code which is working for you . i seems to find it hard to get one better solution . cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Posting the `FormData` object results in a request with content type multipart/form-data. You have to read the request content like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Upload()
{
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("C:\\Somefolder");
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var myParameter = provider.FormData.GetValues("myParameter").FirstOrDefault();
    var count = provider.FileData.Count;

    return count + " / " + myParameter;
}
```

BTW, this will save the file in the path specified, which is `C:\\SomeFolder` and you can get the local file name using `provider.FileData[0].LocalFileName;`

Please take a look at [MSDN code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-File-Upload-a8c0fb0d) and [Henrik's blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

Comment: This looks promising for my scenario; but how does a C# (not jQuery) client call this method? I need to pass two string args AND an XML file.

Comment: `Task<string>` getting error at this point . any ideas how to pass observable array and file to controller . cheers