# Creating a mail attachment from multipart/form-data in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I need to send mail from my webapi. This is pretty straight forward. What I want to do is send the mail with an attachment that is uploaded through my front-end **without saving this file to file system**. As far as I know the *MultipartFormDataStreamProvider* class saves the file to file system. Any idea how I can use the multipart stream to create a System.Net.Mail.Attachment?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723064/webapi-formdata-upload-to-db-with-extra-parameters