# How to pass observableArray to controller with formdata?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, file-upload, knockout.js

I got a upload control when i click on upload a file after browsing i need to send that file to controller and with that i need to send additionally a ObservableArray(which has related data) to normal controller .

I'm clueless how to deal this stuff tired lots and lots of stuff and i ended up with nothing cool .

**My Viewmodel code on upload button click :**

```
self.FFAttach = function () {
                    var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
                    var fileInput = document.getElementById('FFtoSP');

                    ////Iterating through each files selected in fileInput

                    for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                        //Appending each file to FormData object
                        formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
                    }

                    //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', '/WorkCompletion/Upload/');

                    xhr.send(formdata);

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

                            path = xhr.responseText;
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    }
}
```

**My controller code :**

```
  [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(string id)
{

    string uploadedPath = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; //Uploaded file

        //Use the following properties to get file's name, size and MIMEType
        int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        fileName = "Contract" + "_" + "CreateContract" + "_" + fileName;
        string mimeType = file.ContentType;
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), fileName);



        //To save file, use SaveAs method
        file.SaveAs(path); //File will be saved in application root


        byte[] fileData = null;
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream)) { fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength); }
        uploadedPath = UploadToSharepoint(path, id, fileName, file, fileData); 


    }
    return Json(uploadedPath);

}
```

The above code works fine if i want to send a file and save it further but nothing is happening for me  when i try to send a obeservable array .

I tried something like passing oberservable as parameter and yes it wont work as expected and tried appending `formdata.append("myparam", ko.toJS(self.AttachmentUsableArray()));` when i keep this piece of code the debugger in controller even hit sadly .

**Links i been refering you may find handy :**

[Webapi ajax formdata upload with extra parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177237/webapi-ajax-formdata-upload-with-extra-parameters)

[File upload Jquery WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497944/file-upload-jquery-webapi)

Any ideas are appreciated .

Comment: You send an observable array the same way you would send any other array.  It won't be observable from the web page, however; that's not how MVC works.  If you want it to have observable characteristics, you have to build that yourself, using Javascript.  Observable arrays can be converted to ordinary arrays.

Comment: point noted mate . i my post above i haven't metioned my view model and server model functions indeed i built pretty cool which works well with MVVM pattern . As you can observe i an trying `XMLhttpRequest` where i used to do lot of ajax call to controllers and pass my observablearray which works fine . any work around mate using ajax call or whatever .