# Cant upload file to ASP.NET MVC with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload a file to my controller but its taking it as null, while the toUser is accepting right.

I am using `System.Web.Http`, so I cant use `System.Web.Mvc`

MessageController.cs

```
[Route("api/messages/saveChatAttachment/{toUser}"), HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveAttachment(HttpPostedFileBase file, int toUser)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, toUser);
}
```

jQuery

```
var attachment;

$('#chatAttachment').on('change', function (e) {
  if (e.target.files.length) {
    attachment = e.target.files[0];
  }
});

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', attachment);

$.ajax({
  url: '/api/messages/saveChatAttachment/' + toUser,
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (data) {

  }
})
```

Comment: You need to set `contentType: false` and modify your controller - refer [Upload file using WebApi, ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863434/upload-file-using-webapi-ajax)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much :)

Comment: did you try adding toUser to formData? not in the url? my code would be like:    formData.append("file", attachment);
   formData.append("toUser", toUser); try to remove contentType?

Comment: @VictorXie Yep I did, and still the file was comming as null. The solution that StephenMuecke wrote, it works perfectly

Comment: good to see you get it resolved. :)

Comment: @VictorXie Thank you:)