# I can't upload my files using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, http-post, image-uploading

```
            $scope.uploadFiles = function () {
             //debugger;
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/upload/',
                data: formdata,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            };

            // SEND THE FILES.
            $http(request)
                .success(function (d) {
                    alert(d);
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
        }
```

i am getting in console window like 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/upload/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:55555' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS angular-file-upload cannot upload data to WebAPI 2 CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142643/angularjs-angular-file-upload-cannot-upload-data-to-webapi-2-cors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, the app is running at `http://localhost:55555` and you are trying to send a `POST` request to `http://localhost/upload/` (which really means `http://localhost:80/upload/`). Your browser is not allowing you to do this since `http://localhost:80/` and `http://localhost:55555/` are different **origins**.

Perhaps you meant to say `http://localhost:55555/upload/`? This would solve your issue.

Otherwise you need to [disable CORS in your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/5780097) or add the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in your server at `http://localhost:80/`.

Comment: Thanks....i tried http://localhost:55555/upload/ also but getting same issue.i will try 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * otherwise i need write in services to upload images using C# or i should use some upload.php to move.